# how do I generate multiprocessing jobs inside a list without making duplicates?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jobs

How do I make a multiprocessor system work, which makes new jobs inside a list? 
I keep getting:

> assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
>   AttributeError: 'Worker' object has no attribute '_popen'

which makes sense, because I'm basically making multiple instances of the same job... so how do i fix that? do I need to set up a multiprocessor pool?

let me know if I need to clarify things more.

here is my multiprocessing class:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, output_path, source, file_name):
        self.output_path = output_path
        self.source = source
        self.file_name = file_name

    def run(self):

        t = HTML(self.source)
        output = open(self.output_path+self.file_name+'.html','w')
        word_out = open(self.output_path+self.file_name+'.txt','w')  
        try:
            output.write(t.tokenized)

            for w in word_list:
                if w:
                    word_out.write(w+'\n')

            word_out.close()
            output.close()
            word_list = []

        except IndexError: 
            output.write(s[1])
            output.close()
            word_out.close()

        except UnboundLocalError:
            output.write(s[1])
            output.close()
            word_out.close()
```

here is the class that implements this whole thing.

```
class implement(HTML):

    def __init__(self, input_path, output_path):
        self.input_path = input_path
        self.output_path = output_path

    def ensure_dir(self, directory):
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        return directory    

    def prosses_epubs(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.input_path+"\\"):
            epubs = [root+file for file in files if file.endswith('.epub')]
            output_file = [self.ensure_dir(self.output_path+"\\"+os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(e))[0]+'_output\\') for e in epubs]

        count = 0 
        for e in epubs:
            epub = epubLoader(e)

            jobs = []

            # this is what's breaking everything right here. I'm not sure how to fix it. 
            for output_epub in epub.get_html_from_epub():                
                worker = Worker(output_file[count], output_epub[1], output_epub[0])
                jobs.append(worker)
                worker.start()

            for j in jobs:
                j.join()

            count += 1
        print "done!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = implement('some local directory', 'some local directory')    
    test.prosses_epubs()
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated. also let me know if something I'm doing in my code can be done better... I'm always trying to learn how to do things the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Don't use classes when functions suffice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0#t=9m26s). In this case, your classes
  each have essentially one meaty method, and the `__init__` method is
  simply holding arguments used in the meaty method. You can make your
  code sleeker by just making the meaty method a function and passing
  the arguments directly to it.
- Separate the idea of "jobs" (i.e. tasks) from the idea of "workers"
  (i.e. processes). Your machine has a limited number of processors,
  but the number of jobs could be far greater. You don't want to open a
  new process for each job since that might swamp your CPUs --
  essentially fork-bombing yourself.
- Use the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to guarantee that your file handles get
  closed. I see `output.close()` and `word_out.close()` getting called
  in three different places each. You can eliminate all those lines by
  using the `with`-statement, which will automatically close those file
  handles once Python leaves the `with`-suite.
- I think a [multiprocessing Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) would work well with your code. The jobs can be sent to the workers in the pool
  using `pool.apply_async`. Each call queues a job which will wait
  until a worker in the pool is available to handle it. `pool.join()`
  causes the main process to wait until all the jobs are done.
- Use `os.path.join` instead of joining directories with `'\\'`. This
  will make your code compatible with non-Windows machines.
- Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of manually implementing/incrementing
  counters. It's less typing and will make your code a bit more readable.

---

The following code will not run since `epubLoader`, `HTML`, and `word_list` are not defined, but it may give you a clearer idea of what I am suggesting above:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(output_path, source, filename):
    t = HTML(source)
    output_path = output_path+filename
    output = open(output_path+'.html', 'w')
    word_out = open(output_path+'.txt','w')
    with output, word_out:
        try:
            output.write(t.tokenized)

            for w in word_list:
                if w:
                    word_out.write(w+'\n')

            word_list = []

        except IndexError: 
            output.write(s[1])

        except UnboundLocalError:
            output.write(s[1])


def ensure_dir(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    return directory    


def process_epubs(input_path, output_path):
    pool = mp.Pool()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
        epubs = [os.path.join(root, file) for file in files
                 if file.endswith('.epub')]
        output_file = [
            ensure_dir(
                os.path.join(
                    output_path,
                    os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(e))[0] + '_output')
                for e in epubs)]

    for count, e in enumerate(epubs):
        epub = epubLoader(e)
        for filename, source in epub.get_html_from_epub():
            pool.apply_async(
                worker,
                args=(output_file[count], source, filename))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print "done!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_epubs('some local directory', 'some local directory')
```